# Python Error : "InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found"

Tags: python, web-scraping

scraping data from aliexpress and appear this error :

```
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://www.aliexpress.com/category/100003109/women-clothing-accessories.html']"
```

Code :

```
cats_list = []

for cat in cats:

    cat_link = list(cat.absolute_links)
    cat_name = cat.text
    cat_dict ={"name":cat_name , "link" :cat_link}
    cats_list.append(cat_dict)
print(cats_list)
```

getting all names & Links as that:

```
[{'name': "Women's Fashion", 'link': ['https://www.aliexpress.com/category/100003109/women-clothing-accessories.html']}, {'name': "Men's Fashion", 'link': ['https://www.aliexpress.com/category/100003070/men-clothing-accessories.html']}
```

then

```
r=  await asession.get(cats_list[0]["link"])

await r.html.arender(sleep=8,scrolldown=3)

products = r.html.find("manhattan--content--1KpBbUi")**
```

*can't complete because this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the correct link. For example, to scrape the link in the first item of your list:

```
r=  await asession.get(cats_list[0]["link"][0])
```

`link` is a list, and the url is the first item from it.

Comment: when print(products)  return []...no data  & i want all the links

Comment: That's a different issue alltogether than your original question. You issue above was related to `InvalidSchema: No connection adapters`. My answer addressed the your question as asked.